# Correcting a Function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to write a function that will clean a large dataframe of data. The function below is not working. Any thoughts on how to make this work is greatly appreciated!

```
function(x){
    x_4 <- x[x$gene_affected %in% c("ENSG00000171862","ENSG00000121879", "ENSG00000051382", "ENSG00000198793", "ENSG00000142208", "ENSG00000105221", "ENSG00000117020", "ENSG00000145675", "ENSG00000165699", "ENSG00000103197", "ENSG00000104884"), ]
    x_5 <- x_4[x_4$consequence_type %in% c("missense_variant", "inframe_deletion", "frameshift_variant", "stop_gained", "inframe_insertion", "stop_lost", "stop_retained_variant", "splice_acceptor_variant", "splice_donor_variant", "splice_region_variant", "synonymous_variant"), ]  
    x_6 <- x_5[myvars]
    x_7<- x_6[!duplicated(x_6), ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give 10 lines of your data.frame and the error message you get?

Comment: Also, if you want to asssign data outside of the function, you have to use the double arrow: `x_4 <<- x[x$gene_`...

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?  For starters, you have no return value and it's an anonymous function.  Try adding `x_7` on its own line under `x_7<- x_6[!duplicated(x_6), ]` and then make `f <- function(x) ...`. Then run `f(x)`

Comment: if you dont explicitly write a return statement the function will return the last executed line in your case  x_7<- x_6[!duplicated(x_6), ]
without knowing much abt your data nothing else I can say

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer your question without a clear explanation of your intended result and what your actual result is, but my first guess is that you need to **return** the value of the function, like this:

```
f = function(x){
    x_4 <- x[x$gene_affected %in% c("ENSG00000171862","ENSG00000121879", "ENSG00000051382", "ENSG00000198793", "ENSG00000142208", "ENSG00000105221", "ENSG00000117020", "ENSG00000145675", "ENSG00000165699", "ENSG00000103197", "ENSG00000104884"), ]
    x_5 <- x_4[x_4$consequence_type %in% c("missense_variant", "inframe_deletion", "frameshift_variant", "stop_gained", "inframe_insertion", "stop_lost", "stop_retained_variant", "splice_acceptor_variant", "splice_donor_variant", "splice_region_variant", "synonymous_variant"), ]  
    x_6 <- x_5[myvars]
    x_7<- x_6[!duplicated(x_6), ]
    # if you don't have this return phrase below, the function will not produce anything
    return(list(x=x, x_4=x_4, x_5=x_5, x_6=x_6, x_7=x_7))
}
```

if you assign a result:

```
result <- f(x)
```

Then you can access your result with

```
result[['x_7']]
```

**Please consider reading this short article on how to write functions in R:**

http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html

Answer (score 1):

Without having the data, it's difficult to produce a working set of code. But `print(x_7)` at the end of your code will make the function print what you want it to.

```
yourFunction <- function(x){
                x_4 <- x[x$gene_affected %in% c("ENSG00000171862","ENSG00000121879", 
                        "ENSG00000051382", "ENSG00000198793", "ENSG00000142208", 
                        "ENSG00000105221", "ENSG00000117020", "ENSG00000145675", 
                        "ENSG00000165699", "ENSG00000103197", "ENSG00000104884"), ]
                x_5 <- x_4[x_4$consequence_type %in% c("missense_variant", "inframe_deletion", 
                        "frameshift_variant", "stop_gained", "inframe_insertion", 
                        "stop_lost", "stop_retained_variant", "splice_acceptor_variant", 
                        "splice_donor_variant", "splice_region_variant", "synonymous_variant"), ]  
                x_6 <- x_5[myvars]
                x_7<- x_6[!duplicated(x_6), ]
                print(x_7)
             }

resultDF <- yourFunction(yourDataFrame)
```

Comment: This is also a good answer, but in general I would not use `print` to return values from a function. If you add a new line `new_x <- 0` to the bottom of `yourFunction`, the return value changes to 0. Better to explicitly `return` the value you want, especially for R novices like OP

Comment: I choose to use `print` because the local variables, such as `x_5` and `x_6`, stay local and consequently out of memory. Makes for tidier general usage. But yes, it does take a bit of know-how to make sure `print` is last. Also, I like to keep the functions in memory so I can reuse them later.

Comment: Also likely that OP will think all functions need to end with `print` to return a value :P